# Accessing already downloaded Ljspeech dataset; cannot find data in directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

Edit: I tried doing `!pip install pydub` and `!pip install apache_beam` before downloading the dataset

I downloaded the dataset "Ljspeech" to my Google Drive on Colab(Tensorflow version 2.7.0), but when I try to load the data from the directory again after restarting the runtime, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Dataset ljspeech: could not find data in /content/drive/MyDrive/data. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.
```

I downloaded the dataset the first time by tfds.load() function;

```
!pip install pydub
!pip install apache_beam
dataset = tfds.load('ljspeech',split=['train'],download=True,data_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/data')
```

and tried to load the dataset again after I reset the runtime but it just tries to download the whole dataset again. The exact same script worked just fine for other datasets e.g. mnist, cifar10 etc., so I can't figure out what I'm missing here.
I also tried downloading the data like this:

```
dataset = tfds.audio.Ljspeech(data_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/data')
dataset.download_and_prepare()
```

and then tried to load the data again with tfds.load(download=False),
but it just returned an error and didn't make much difference. Can the dataset be the problem somehow?

Comment: I replicated the issue using same `TF 2.7` and got different error message. I used `!pip install pydub` then able to execute the same code and able to download the dataset.

Comment: @TFer2 I tried what you suggested, using `!pip install pydub` (and also `!pip install apache_beam`, which was required to download the dataset), but I got the same error message.

Comment: Please follow the [gist](https://github.com/keithito/tacotron) as mentioned in the official documentation of ljspeech. If any issue still persists, do comment so that we can find more ways to help you here, if the problem still holds validity.